# Exclude all pending changes in Visual Studio TFS by default

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, visual-studio-2013

With visual studio TFS integration, I don't like that it has all files in "Included Changes" by default. I keep accidentally checking in things I didn't mean to. I'd prefer to have everything show under "Excluded Changes" and I would include the files I want in the changeset one by one. Like you do in Git with **git add** when building a commit.

This would be like clicking "Exclude All" every time you go into Pending Changes, but without having to remember to do it.

Does anyone know of a way to configure this? I am using VS2013 Pro.

Comment: What's wrong with not changing the files you don't want to change?

Comment: Because I'll often times have changes that are for testing purposes, or that are for a different project in the same repository but I may not be ready to check those in.

Comment: Use branches, or shelve your work before you go off doing testing, or use the "My Work" feature (if it's in the "Pro" edition - I'm not sure). If you could default to "Exclude", then you will certainly miss actual changes. You need to keep your pending changes close to what you want to check in. Not exact, but close. Keep in mind you're building and testing against those changes. If you have changes you're not going to check in, then  you're testing code that you're not going to check in.

Comment: @JohnSaunders I respectfully disagree with this, actually. I think it's better to exclude by default; it's the responsibility of the developer to create a meaningful commit, and that means choosing what to include. Exclusion is also better because TFS uses the read-only flag to determine whether a file has been touched - and this can lead to a lot of included files that have no changes. (Truthfully, I think the real answer to this question is to use git - especially since that's now an excellent alternative to TFS's branching, merging, and committing, which is less than stellar in my opinion.)

Comment: @jedd.ahyoung: are you suggesting that you can change a file (thereby making it writable), then set the file read-only, and TFS will see the file as not touched?

Comment: @JohnSaunders Truthfully, you got me. I'm not sure if it would go that far - but I can confirm that if you don't check out a file, but remove the read-only flag in Explorer, that TFS will place the file in your pending changes (it's how TFS knows that you have a file checked out). I'm definitely going to test the statement you provided, though.

Comment: I'm thinking it may be using a file system watcher, and not just checking the read-only flag. I have also made external changes to a file, seen it listed in "excluded changes", then undone the changes, and seen the file removed from "excluded changes". Clearly, that's using more than the read-only flag.